# Why is My .HTACCESS Code Not Rewriting the Title Tag?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On my website, whenever there is: `photo?title=SOME-URL`
I want to change it with `photo/SOME-URL`

For example, check the bottom-left corner of this image:

[image]

Even though I'm redirecting internally and externally, it still does not work.

The external redirect is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error.

What am I missing?

I have this in my `.htaccess`:
Note: (domain name replaced with example)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# This sets my public folder as main directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]

# To remove the query title and introduce looks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+photo(?:\.php)?\?title=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ photo/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^photo/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ photo.php?title=$1 [NC,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Your image shows the URL (resolved from the HTML source) when you hover over an anchor on the page. Any redirects/rewrites in `.htaccess` are obviously not going to change that. To change the URL in the image (the URL in the HTML source) you need to actually change the HTML source! With regards to the 500 error, you should check your server's error log, although I suspect it is to do with the ordering of the rules (they are in the wrong order) and the last rule that appends the `.php` extension.

Comment: ... You are rewriting the request to `/public` so the rule that checks/rewrites `/photo/<title>` is not going to match. The later rule then erroneously appends the `.php` extension (creating a rewrite loop). However, there are other unknowns/inconsistencies here... are you hosting multiple domains? Why are you checking the hostname in the first rule block, but not later - is that intentional?

Comment: The photo.php file is also in the "public" folder. With the hover, I just wanted to highlight the obvious - my original URL. I'm aware that I have to change it later within the code (when the rewrite actually works).
I'm not hosting multiple domains. I'm just fixing problems one by one, and find codes that work. While I do understand PHP quite well, I'm not good in regex and modifying the .htaccess file (although I understand some of the basics). Thank you for the help. Any ideas how to improve all that?

Comment: I've fixed the issue by myself. The problem was that the RewriteRule for the photo should be in a separate .htaccess INSIDE the public folder. The rest should remain in the root folder. I also improved these codes and removed unnecessary redirects.